# groupby and size. How to store count values in a seperate variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'A': ['Red', 'Red', 'Green', 'Red', 'Green', 'Red'], 'B' : ['Red','Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Red') & (df['B'] == 'Red'), 'new'] = 'RR'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Green') & (df['B'] == 'Red'), 'new'] = 'GR'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Red') & (df['B'] == 'Green'), 'new'] = 'RG'
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'Green') & (df['B'] == 'Green'), 'new'] = 'GG'
d = df.groupby(['new']).size()
```

After applying groupby and size. I want to store count values in seperate variabes. For example RR = 4, GR = 2, RG = 0, GG = 0.

[This is the result i got after applying groupby and size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEt8g.png)

Comment: Dynamic variable naming should be avoid. Instead, use `dict`: `vals = d.to_dict()`, and you can get `vals['RR']` which is `4`.

Comment: you can use pandas value_counts() function

Comment: But it does not gives me values in a seperate variable. I want to assign those count values to variables